# Haskell function with infinite list as argument

Tags: haskell

After poking around the other posts involving infinite lists and my error messages, I still can't solve my issues.

I am just learning Haskell, and I thought that implementing the Newton-Raphson Square Root method would be an interesting first problem. Here is my code:

```
next_ ::  (Floating a) => a -> a -> a
next_ n x = (x + n/x)/2

repeat_ :: (Floating a) => ( a -> a ) -> a -> [a]
repeat_ f a = a : (repeat_ f (f a))

within :: (Ord a, Floating a) => a -> [a] -> a
within eps (x:xs)
  | (abs (x / b - 1.0)) < eps = b
  | otherwise = within eps (b:bs)
  where b = head xs
        bs = tail xs
```

The code is compiled by GHCi just fine. `eps` is the max distance between 2 successive square root approximations before the final answer is returned.

I split the three parts into three functions, with the intention of writing a `sqrt` function which calls `within` with `repeat_` and `next_`. I have tested `repeat_` and `next_`, and both of them work as expected. However, when I run `within .01 (repeat_ (next_ 2.0) 2.5)`, I get this error message:

```
<interactive>:44:1: error:
• Non type-variable argument
    in the constraint: Num ([a] -> a2 -> a1)
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
• When checking the inferred type
    it :: forall a a1 a2.
          (Num ([a] -> a2 -> a1), Floating a, Floating a1, Ord a1) =>
          a2 -> [a1] -> a1
```

Reading through the error message and googling it, I am still lost. I have read through the similar questions here and couldn't fix the problem. The issue, I think, is the infinite list as an argument. I know that Haskell is Lazy, so it will only evaluate as many numbers as it needs until the return condition is met. I think that the above implementation is correct (i.e. `(x:xs)` for the inf. list), but I am not sure. The typeclasses are also an area of concern. After searching and reading, I am still shaky on the typeclass for `within`. Since the infinite list is being evaluated in the function, does within need a type declaration like `repeat_` where it is stated that `repeat_` takes in a function?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Marked as Duplicate! The problem was that I was not adding a zero infront of the '.01', which must occur in Haskell. This is because in haskell, `.` is the concatenation function - i.e. (f . g) h = f (g ( h))